# Take the first n files from a directory starting with a particular letter in alphabetical order to another directory

Tags: command-line, find, sort

I need to take the first 3 files from a directory starting with letter b in alphabetical order to another directory. I've come up with this command:

```
find /users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in \
  -name "b*" | sort | head -3
```

And it produces the proper files, but I can't do anything with them. Ideally I'd just pipe the output of the above command to `mv`, but I don't think that's possible.

(P.S. I have to do this without `grep`, `sed` or `awk`)

Comment: @qbi I actually did try that with mv, and just now with cp, but both times I got the message "Illegal variable name." Could the problem be that I'm working in tcsh and not bash?

Comment: Yes, tcsh is in some sense completely different than bash.

Comment: @qbi Okay, so I've tried set file = 'find /users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in \
  -name "b*" | sort | head -3', then echo $files, and I get the message find: No match. What now? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: I changed my answer. So it fits to tcsh.

Comment: @qbi Tried your new answer and it gives the message "cp: No match." Hmm...

Comment: Does `find` (plus the other commands) give an output?

Comment: @qbi find /users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in \ -name "b*" | sort | head -3 gives this output:              /users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in/ba2b.c
/users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in/ba2.c
/users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in/ba3.c With newlines after each file, this comment section doesn't show that.

Comment: could you try `set nonomatch` and enter the command?

Comment: @qbi I typed set nonomatch, then re-set the variable (I called it FILES), and typed cp $FILES /users/students/ejackson. I got the message cp: invalid option -- 'm'
Try `cp --help' for more information.

Comment: @qbi Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing `find` output (very bad idea), you can take advantage of the fact that `for` loops over files in an ordered way:

```
i=0; for b in /path/to/files/b*; do (( ++i < 4 )) && echo mv -v -- "$b" /path/to/destination; done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to actually move the files.
Here it is with ugly comments:

```
# set a variable to 0 so we can increment it
i=0
# glob for the files starting with b
for b in /path/to/files/b*; do 
   # test how many times the loop has been run and if it's less than 4...
   (( ++i < 4 )) && 
     # ... then move the files*  
     echo mv -v -- "$b" /path/to/destination
done
```

<sub>*This won't happen until you remove `echo` from the start of the line - instead it will echo out which files will be moved and where (expand the variables for each iteration)</sub>

<sub>I don't know if this works in tcsh, but it works in bash, so might help other Ubuntu users who mainly use bash</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can take a list of file and process them through a for loop in a shell script, or if you on the command line itself (it will just be harder to reader)

Check out this article at [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/). [Another tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/) as well.

You should be able to do something like

```
for f in `find /users/students/ejackson/A3-ejackson-55688-114906/CS282in -name "b*" | sort | head -3`
do
    cp $f [target]
done
```

Comment: The same logic can be applied in other shells or perl, etc.

Comment: parsing the output of `find` is not a good idea though

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using `tcsh`. The family of C-Shells is not compatible with Bourne shells. This command might work:

```
set THREE_FILES=`find …`
cp $THREE_FILES NEW_DIRECTORY
```

The first `set` command makes a new enviroment variable called `THREE_FILES` and saves the output into that variable. The `cp` takes the three files and copies them to the `NEW_DIRECTORY`.